# C# Unity как обратится к переменным класса из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп

У меня есть главный класс Game привязанный к Main Camera, в нем хранятся переменные, которые я должен читать/редактировать из других скриптов.

Как это реализовать? В Unity и ООП новичок, в интернете не смог найти ответов.

Пример:

Файл 1:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    ArrayList antibodies = new ArrayList();  
    // другой код
}
```

Второй файл:

```
public class Skin : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "antibody "){
            (тут как-то достать antibodies).Remove(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как один из возможных вариантов - объявить переменную с камерой в классе Skin и получить у нее компонент скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, у поля `antibodies` не задан модификатор доступа. По умолчанию он задается как `private`, а значит вы никак не можете получить к нему доступ извне.

Вообще получить доступ можно разными способами и зависят они от Ваших целей, которые мне неизвестны.

Например:

- Сделать поле `public static antibodies`. Тогда к нему можно обратится через имя класса: `Game.antibodies.Remove(other)`. Но, обычно, это плохая практика. Вы открываете это поле для доступа из любого места в программе, что превращает код в лапшу.
- Сделать класс `Game` синглтоном и поле `public antibodies`. Что аналогично первому варианту, наверняка превратит Ваш код в лапшу.
- Поле `antibodies` делаем `public`, а объект `Game` ищем с помощью [`Object.FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) или [`GameObject.FindWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html). Но это плохая практика. Создаёт не явные зависимости и ухудшает производетельность (особенно если объектов на сцене много).
- Держать ссылку на компонент `Game` внутри компонента `Skin`, и опять же, поле `antibodies` делаем `public`. Тогда получаем доступ как `_game.antibodies.Remove(other)` где `_game` ссылка на компонент типа `Game`. (Как назначить эту ссылку это уже совсем другая история. Например, при создании и инициализации ваших 'antibody'. Либо настроить префаб на сцене и прокинуть ссылку в редакторе в поле помеченное [`SerializelField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html). Вариантов много). *В общем*, это самый нормальный вариант работы с зависимостями.

Наверняка есть ещё варианты, но не зная задач не приходят в голову. Остановимся на самом нормальном в общем случае.

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Antibody> antibodies = new List<Antibody>();  
    // другой код
}

public class Skin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Game _game;

    public void Init(Game game)
    {
        _game = game;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.TryGetComponent<Antibody>(out var antibody))
            _game.antibodies.Remove(antibody);        
    }
}
```

При инстанциировании объекта `Skin` вызываем метод `Init` и передаём ссылку на `Game`. Либо кидаем ссылку вручную в компонент объекта на сцене в редакторе.

---

Немного не по теме:

- ArrayList лучше заменить на [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) из [System.Collection.Generic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.8). Generic типы очень полезны за счет статической типизации. Кроме того позволят избежать неявных упаковок и распаковок.
- вместо проверки объекта Unity по тегу, лучше проверять по наличию компонента. Например на объекты `antibody` добавить скрипт `Antibody`. Даже если он будет пустой. Так как вы не можете гарантировать что объект с тегом имеет на себе нужные компоненты. К тому же, у одного объекта может быть только один тег, а компонентов может быть сколько угодно. Что если вам понадобится пометить объект двумя "тегами"? Да и от опечаток никто не застрахован. Очень легко ошибиться в написании тега в коде, а вот при ошибке в написании имени типа Вам подскажет среда разработки или компилятор. Соответствено и список у вас будет `List<Antibody>`
- очень похоже, что Ваш класс `Game` собирается стать глобальным монолитным классом "менеджером" с кучей функционала, зависимостей и ответственностью. Тоже плохая практика. Ответственность следует разделять на более мелкие классы, и давать соответствующие им имена. Имена классов `Game`, `Manager`, `Controller`, `Helper` и подобные вот прям вообще не дают представления о том для чего они нужны, и обычно являются индикаторами таких вот классов-монолитов.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Я уже реализовал через GameObject.Find но это будет тоже очень полезно!

Comment: Насчет тегов, мне кажется, спорный момент - проверка по тегу более производительный способ чем проверять на наличие компонента, т.е. можно сначала проверять на тег чтобы сразу отсеять много излишних проверок, а затем и убедиться в наличии компонента.

Comment: Не факт. Но я не проверял. Но уж точно не настолько более производительно, чтобы превращать код в месиво из строковых переменных. (К тому же, в новых версиях Unity есть TryGetComponent, который намного производительнее чем GetComponent). Даже сами разработчики Unity советуют отказываться от тегов. Ссылки на источник пока не будет :) Но как только освобожусь, так сразу и добавлю.